# Over come placeholder text with innerText

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

What I want to do is to fill it with text programatically.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textBox").InnerText = "foo";
```

This code works but some websites have a placeholder text. This code will not allow me to fill this as value but instead it as a placeholder text.

Strangely in some text box, it will be paste as value when there are a placeholder text. But some text box it wont.

Another scenario is that when it is `innerText` is placed as a placeholder text, all I have to do is click on that text box and write something next to it. This will act as a text box values.

Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `value` attribute of the `<input id='textBox'>` elment not the innertext.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textBox").SetAttribute("value", "text text text");
```